# docker push keeps pushing

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-toolbox

I'm trying to push docker image to dockerhub. It started good, pushing several layers simultaneusly. But when it got to the last 2 layers, something weird is happening. After it has pushed 100%, it will start all over from 0%. This seems to continue to infinity. I'm on Windows 7, I have newest dockertoolbox installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might have been a timeout. It sometimes goes over 100%, and perhaps the timeout occurred during that period. Which led me to think that it just repushes after it reaches to 100%.